# Is the result of (new Uint8Array(1))[0] = 0x100 undefined?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

Looking at the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/), the following behavior doesn't seem to be defined clearly :

```
var array = new Uint8Array( 1 );
var result = ( array[ 0 ] = 0x100 );

// Is result === 0x100 or 0 ?
```

Chrome is returning `0x100` instead of `0`, but can I trust this result to be consistent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here:

```
var result = ( array[ 0 ] = 0x100 );
```

is actually the same (a short-hand) as setting both array and result with the same value at the same time (the parenthesis does not matter as 0x100 is the one being evaluated and passed to result):

```
var result = array[ 0 ] = 0x100;
```

or expanded:

```
array[ 0 ] = 0x100;
var result = 0x100;
```

so obviously `result` would in this case be 0x100 (256).

But the content of the *array* is 0 as you can see if you log it directly:

```
console.log(array[ 0 ]);
```

(if you used `Uint8ClampedArray` instead the value would be 0xff or 255).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/8ehPb/)**

So in that case the result will be consistent but by-passing the array in relation to the result variable and the value set. Array will be set too, but the value is fit to the unsigned byte range while the value is as-is for the result var.

Comment: I'm not sure. In C++, assuming that B is an object, `int A = B = 0x100` would do something like `A = B.operator=(0x100)`. Would this operator overload return something else than `0x100`, then A wouldn't be equal to the rightmost value. Since such a concept  doesn't seems incoherent, I would except finding it in JS too. Would you have a reference on a standard which could confirm your answer ?

Comment: @MaëlNison the fiddle confirms my answer as you can see in console. Since you are not doing a compare the parenthesis won't return a boolean value but the set value (0x100). JS uses C syntaxes but is not related to C as such (for example, is type-less and dynamic).

Comment: Sure, as I wrote in the question I tested it myself, I was more looking for an academic answer :) But you're right, I checked it on the [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1) and it clearly says that in a `lref = rval` situation, the underlying `PutVal(lref, rval)` operation doesn't return anything, and that the result of the whole expression should be `rval` itself.